# Как сделать задержку при обращении к базе данных?

Tags: gwt, java, java-ee

Пишу приложение на java + gwt. В приложении идет работа с несколькими базами данных. Проблема в том, что запрос данных из таблиц происходит быстрее, чем смена базы, что приводит к некорректно отображаемым данным. Как сделать задержку для обновления таблиц при том, что метод serverCall ничего не возвращает?

```
reps.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler() {
        public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {
        final String repPath = reps.getValue(reps.getSelectedIndex());
            RootPanel.get("loadingbarImg").setVisible(true);    
            reps.setEnabled(false);
    //в следующей строчке идет замена базы данных
            serverCall("changeRep" + repPath);
     //затем два метода запрашивают данные из таблиц,
     //но смена базы данных не успевает завершится,
     //поэтому подтягиваются данные из старой базы      
            serverCall("git");
            serverCall("bugs");
            reps.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    );
```

Comment: Thread.sleep(N) ?

Comment: Ах да, дело происходит на клиентской части gwt, так что это не сработает

Comment: видимо для вашего метода serverCall, надо добавить еще один параметр типа  boolean, который будет определять является запрос синхронным/асинхронным. и уже внутри этого метоад сделать логику ожидания результата выполнения команды если `async = false;`

Comment: А зачем вам задержка на стороне клиента? Вы делаете неправильно, ваш метод ненадёжен. Какой величины паузу вы хотите встроить? Делайте по-взрослому:

* клиент посылает запрос на замену базы
* сервер присылает ответ, что/когда база успешна заменена
* после этого клиент посылает запросы к новой базе

Comment: @VladD urls.by/1s2z Сам уже понял. Хотелось просто побыстрее с этим разделаться.